# How does $\ x_i = (x_i - \overline{x})$ in the proof for ordinary least squares regression?

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, least-squares

I am trying to understand how this:

$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i(y_i - \overline{y})-\beta_1\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i(x_i - \overline{x})$

Could possibly simplify to this:

$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})-\beta_1\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})(x_i - \overline{x})$
$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})-\beta_1\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})^2$

Solve the above equation for $\beta_1 $ and you have your OLS estimator. I understand the entire proof up until this point.

Am I crazy? Unless the average value of $\ x_i $ is zero (which nothing in a linear regressions says it has to be) isn't this impossible? I'm convinced this is a typo.

Comment: The difference between the "simplified" and original expression is $\sum(\bar x(y_i-\bar y)-\beta_1\bar x(x_i-\bar x))$ or $\bar x(\sum(y_i-\bar y)-\beta_1\sum(x_i-\bar x)$ or $\bar x(0-\beta_1\cdot0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you see it from here:

$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y})x_i - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y})\overline{x}  $

But:
$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y})\overline{x} = \overline{x} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y}) =0 $.

Since: $ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}y_i - \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \overline{y} =  \sum_{i = 1}^{n}y_i - n\overline{y} =  n\overline{y} -n\overline{y} =0 $

It follows that:
$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y})x_i - 0 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y})x_i   $

For the other part, following the same pattern:
$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})(x_i - \overline{x}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})x_i - \overline{x} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})  = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})x_i $

Comment: Reworking it backwards makes so much sense! Thanks Snoopy!